# Issue when inserting new entity with relationships to existing entities (Entity Framework Core 1.1.0 )

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I have encountered an issue when inserting (`Add` method of EF API) or updating (`Update` method of EF API) entities holding reference properties to existing entities (I call existing entity an entity that already exists in the database, and has its PK properly set).

The model consists in `Place`, `Person`, `Address`, and `Status` :

- A person has many addresses.
- A place has several persons, and also
  several addresses.
- Places, Persons and Addresses have statuses.
- All entities have an Id, Name, Created date and Modified date (these fields are all defined in an abstract `BaseEntity`)

If I create a whole graph for a "Place", with new Persons and new Addresses, and save it in one step, everything is fine.

If I create a Place with Addreses then save it, it is still ok.
But at last when I add an existing person and resave the Place, I have an exception: EF actually tries to insert the existing person, and SQL Server throws an error because EF tried to insert a row with a provided Id (PK are set to be generated by SQL Server).

That means that by default, EF Core 1.1.0 looks like being unable to properly traverse relationships and discover which enitites should be added, and which one should be ignored or updated. It tries to insert an entity which already has its PK set to a positive value.

After doing some research, I discovered the new `DbContext.ChangeTracker.Track()` method of the EF Core 1.1.0 API, and it allows one to execute a callback method on all the entities discovered by traversing the relationships of the root entity.
Thanks to this, I have set up the appropriate State, according to the value of the primary key.

Without this code (in `DbRepository.ApplyStates()`), none of my insert would work, as long as they would refer a relation to an existing entity.

Note that with **EF7 and the DNX CLI**, this scenario would work, even without the DbRepository.ApplyStates() thing.

**Source to reproduce**

*everything is in there: models, DbContext, Repository and test code.*

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
using System.Linq;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

namespace EF110CoreTest
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Seed();
        }

        private static void Seed()
        {
            // Repo
            var statusRepo = new DbRepository<Status>();
            var personRepo = new DbRepository<Person>();
            var addressRepo = new DbRepository<Address>();
            var placeRepo = new DbRepository<Place>();

            // Status
            if (!statusRepo.GetAll().Any())
            {
                statusRepo.InsertOrUpdate(new Status() { Name = "Active" });
                statusRepo.InsertOrUpdate(new Status() { Name = "Archive" });
                statusRepo.SaveChanges();
            }
            var statusActive = statusRepo.GetSingle(1);
            var statusArchive = statusRepo.GetSingle(2);

            // Delete the non static data
            foreach(var address in addressRepo.GetAll()) addressRepo.Delete(address);
            addressRepo.SaveChanges();
            foreach (var place in placeRepo.GetAll()) placeRepo.Delete(place);
            placeRepo.SaveChanges();
            foreach (var person in personRepo.GetAll()) personRepo.Delete(person);
            personRepo.SaveChanges();

            Console.WriteLine("Cleared any existing data");

            /***********************************************************************/

            // Step 1 : a person with status and addresses is saved
            var personWithAddresses = new Person()
            {
                Name = "Jon SNOW",
                Status = statusActive,
                AddressCollection = new List<Address>()
                {
                    new Address() { City = "Castleblack", Status = statusActive },
                    new Address() { City = "Winterfel", Status = statusArchive }
                }
            };
            personRepo.InsertOrUpdate(personWithAddresses);
            personRepo.SaveChanges();

            Console.WriteLine("Step 1 ok");
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);

            /***********************************************************************/

            // Step 2 : Create a place with addresses
            var placeWithAddress = new Place()
            {
                Name = "Castleblack",
                Status = statusActive
            };
            placeWithAddress.AddressCollection.Add(new Address() { City = "Castleblack", Status = statusActive });
            placeRepo.InsertOrUpdate(placeWithAddress);
            placeRepo.SaveChanges();

            Console.WriteLine("Step 2 ok");
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);

            /***********************************************************************/

            // Step 3 : add person to this place
            placeWithAddress.PersonCollection.Add(personWithAddresses);
            placeRepo.InsertOrUpdate(placeWithAddress);
            placeRepo.SaveChanges();

            Console.WriteLine("Step 3 ok");
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
        }
    }

    public class DbRepository<T> where T : BaseEntity
    {
        protected readonly MyContext _context;
        public DbRepository() { _context = new MyContext(); }

        public T GetSingle(int id) => _context.Set<T>().FirstOrDefault(e => e.Id == id);

        public IEnumerable<T> GetAll() => _context.Set<T>().AsEnumerable();

        public void Insert(T entity)
        {
            ApplyStates(entity);
            _context.Add(entity);
        }

        public void Update(T entity)
        {
            ApplyStates(entity);
            _context.Update(entity);
        }

        public void Delete(T entity)
        {
            _context.Remove(entity);
        }

        private void ApplyStates(T entity)
        {
            _context.ChangeTracker.TrackGraph(entity, node =>
            {
                var entry = node.Entry;
                var childEntity = (BaseEntity)entry.Entity;
                entry.State = childEntity.IsNew ? EntityState.Added : EntityState.Modified;
            });
        }

        public void InsertOrUpdate(T entity)
        {
            if (entity.IsNew) Insert(entity); else Update(entity);
        }

        public void SaveChanges()
        {
            var pendingChanges = _context.ChangeTracker.Entries<T>()
                .Where(entry => entry.State == EntityState.Added || entry.State == EntityState.Modified)
                .Select(e => e.Entity)
                .ToList();
            foreach (var entity in pendingChanges)
            {
                entity.Modified = DateTime.Now;
                if (entity.Created == null) entity.Created = DateTime.Now;
            }
            _context.SaveChanges();
        } 
    }

    #region Models
    public abstract class BaseEntity
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public DateTime? Created { get; set; }
        public DateTime? Modified { get; set; }
        [NotMapped]
        public bool IsNew => Id <= 0;
    }

    public class Person : BaseEntity
    {
        public int? StatusId { get; set; }
        public Status Status { get; set; }
        public List<Address> AddressCollection { get; set; } = new List<Address>(); 
    }

    public class Address : BaseEntity
    {
        public string Zip { get; set; }
        public string City { get; set; }
        public int? StatusId { get; set; }
        public Status Status { get; set; }
        public int? PersonId { get; set; }
        public Person Person { get; set; }
        public int? PlaceId { get; set; }
        public Place Place { get; set; }
    }

    public class Place : BaseEntity
    {
        public int? StatusId { get; set; }
        public Status Status { get; set; }
        public List<Person> PersonCollection { get; set; } = new List<Person>();
        public List<Address> AddressCollection { get; set; } = new List<Address>();  
    }

    public class Status : BaseEntity { }
    #endregion

    #region Context
    public class MyContext : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<Status> StatusCollection { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Person> PersonCollection { get; set; } 
        public DbSet<Address> AddressCollection { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Place> PlaceCollection { get; set; }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
        {
            // Basic event fire of model creation
            base.OnModelCreating(builder);

            // Status
            builder.Entity<Status>().ToTable("Status", "Shared");

            // Person
            builder.Entity<Person>().ToTable("Person", "Shared");
            builder.Entity<Person>()
                .HasMany(p => p.AddressCollection)
                .WithOne(a => a.Person);

            // Address
            builder.Entity<Address>().ToTable("Address", "Shared");
            builder.Entity<Address>()
                .HasOne(p => p.Person)
                .WithMany(a => a.AddressCollection);

            // Place
            builder.Entity<Place>().ToTable("Place", "Shared");
            builder.Entity<Place>()
                .HasMany(p => p.AddressCollection)
                .WithOne(p => p.Place);
        }

        protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
        {
            optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(@"Server=(localdb)\mssqllocaldb;Database=EF110CoreTest;Trusted_Connection=True;");
        }
    }
    #endregion
}
```

**Project.json file**

{
    "version": "1.0.0-*",
    "buildOptions": {
      "emitEntryPoint": true
    },

```
"dependencies": {
  "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore": "1.1.0",
  "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer": "1.1.0",
  "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools": "1.1.0-preview4-final"
},

"frameworks": {
  "net461": {}
},

"tools": {
  "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.DotNet": "1.0.0-preview3-final"
}
```

}

**Exception details**

Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbUpdateException: An error occurred while updating the entries. See the inner exception for details. ---> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table 'Person' when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF.

Comment: That's a lot of code. When do you get that exception and is your question about the exception?

Comment: I have the exception on step 3. The exception is not expected, so the question is: is there an issue in my code, or in EFCore 1.1.0 (since it was working on the alpha version still named EF7).

Comment: According to the answer, the comments and my own researches, I targetted more sharply the issue, and thus completely rewrote the question.

Comment: I do not think that is a good edit because now none of the comments between you and kcwu and others makes sense anymore as per the new question. Even his answer doesn't make sense anymore and I can see people downvoting his answer...I think you should rollback the changes and if anything ask another question.

Comment: You're right I will do so.

Comment: I just rolled back to the initial question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I modified some code, please review it.

In class `DbRepository`, added another constructor, to make sure there is the same `DbContext` in different `DbRepository`.

```
public DbRepository(MyContext myContext)
{
    _context = myContext;
}
```

In class `Person` added 2 properties, to ensure the relation between `Person` and `Place`.

```
public int? PlaceId { get; set; }
public Place Place { get; set; }
```

In function `Seed`, modified some code with above modifications.

Firstly, in the part of initialize repository.

```
// Repo
var myContext = new MyContext();
var statusRepo = new DbRepository<Status>(myContext);
var personRepo = new DbRepository<Person>(myContext);
var addressRepo = new DbRepository<Address>(myContext);
var placeRepo = new DbRepository<Place>(myContext);
```

This will make all repository use same database connection.

Secondly, due to those changes, the clear process should change the orders, too.

```
// Delete the non static data
foreach (var address in addressRepo.GetAll()) addressRepo.Delete(address);
addressRepo.SaveChanges();
foreach (var person in personRepo.GetAll()) personRepo.Delete(person);
personRepo.SaveChanges();
foreach (var place in placeRepo.GetAll()) placeRepo.Delete(place);
placeRepo.SaveChanges();
```

In your `Step 1`, I extract the address with `CatsleBlack`, because I guess the one in `Person` and the other one in `Place` should be the same.

So, when you initialize a new `Person`, it will be

```
var castleBlack = new Address {City = "Castleblack", Status = statusActive};
var personWithAddresses = new Person()
{
        Name = "Jon SNOW",
        Status = statusActive,
        AddressCollection = new List<Address>()
        {
            castleBlack,
            new Address() { City = "Winterfel", 
                            Status = statusArchive }
        }    
};
```

Initialize the `Place`

```
var placeWithAddress = new Place()
{
        Name = "Castleblack",
        Status = statusActive
};
placeWithAddress.AddressCollection.Add(castleBlack);
```

Those are what I have done, can save successfully. The `Person` record in db also has its `PlaceId`.

Comment: Thanks for that time taken. I set up your version in my code and it is actually working fine. But my real world project (which still doesn't work) has 2 differences. First, the relationship between Place and Person is a many to many (with join entity of course). Second, it is a MVC / WebAPI / Angular archi, so the context is not the same between a get and a POST. That's why I had NOT shared the context between my repos (but you make a point, in a request scope, the context is shared).

Comment: Here's my updated version of the code, where the relationship between Place and Person is now a many to many: https://gist.github.com/kall2sollies/3734d011f9b724f4131e4d5242c47028 . With a shared context it is still working. So the issue my come from binding obects back to the context once they've been HTTP posted ?

Comment: Hello @kall2sollies , sorry for my late response. If you need to update exist entity in db, maybe you should get it by primary key from db at first, than update the property's value in entity (you can use `AutoMapper` to help to do this task) because you have relations between entities. In my guess, the object you post from HTTP and the one you get from db, they are not the same, because the post one's values of relations may be null.

Comment: Thing is what I do is just basic relationship operations, as I have always done with EF6 and even with EF7 (the alpha version of EF Core) with DNX (the alpha version of DotNet Core). Doing so much stuff (query a light object, use a mapper to fill it...) should not be needed for such a basic scenario as mine !

Comment: Well, that's my experiences of the problem which I faced when first time using EF. maybe you can check the differences between the entity you post from HTTP and the one you get from db, guess we lose something there.

Comment: @kall2sollies in web api and web applications it is best to use one context per request.

Comment: @CodingYoshi: this is exactly what I do using built-in DI framework and registering context with AddScoped()

Comment: @kcwu: at the moment this is what I'm doing! My console proj is an exact mirror of the relationships depth, and it is working fine! Even when I introduce different contexts on purpose, or serialize and deserialize objects to simulate the http post and binding of the WebApi. But in my actual project, it doesn't work. THE difference is on the callbacks of the ChangeTracker.TrackGraph() which does not iterate on the Joining entity on my web project, as it perfectly does in my console app.

Comment: @kall2sollies, maybe you could remove the relations between the entities, and just use properties to maintain them. Because if remove the relations,  we don't need to verify which property(such as relations, it's parent) should ignore when serialize, just serialize all, and post modified back, then deserialize it in your controller.

Comment: @kall2sollies, in this article, they recommend use DTO in Web API, maybe it will help you in handling relations. https://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/data/using-web-api-with-entity-framework/part-4

Comment: @kcwu: the article refers to generic guidelines and is using EF6. I think that DTO's are actually a good practice, but the problem I'm facing here is not just general, it is precisely in migrating a working solution from EF7 to EFCore1.1.0.

Comment: @kall2sollies, it could run correctly when using your architecture with EF6? if yes, could you compare the difference when serialized object in Web API with EF 6, EF 7 and EFCore 1.1.0?

Comment: I do not wish to enable EF6 in this test. But I clearly stated that EF7 works as I expect whereas EFCore 1.1 doesn't. As CodingYoshi stated in a comment, I rolled back the question to its initial state and marked your answer as accepted. Now I will post a new question!

Comment: See question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41459479/attaching-an-entity-with-a-mix-of-existing-and-new-entities-in-its-graph-entity for the rewritten issue.